# Django can't destroy and create test databases properly

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-unittest

When I try to run my unittest, this is what I get:

```
python manage.py test dbank --settings=databank_web.settings.dqs.dev_hooman
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Creating test database for alias 'global'...
Creating test database for alias 'optin_db'...
Creating test database for alias 'vpd3'...
Creating test database for alias 'user_db'...
Creating test database for alias 'vpd1'...
Creating test database for alias 'vpd2'...
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.327s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
Warning: Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist
```

It couldn't destroy the database. It gets better, when I rerun the test:

```
python manage.py test dbank --settings=databank_web.settings.dqs.dev_hooman
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Creating test database for alias 'global'...
Got an error creating the test database: (1007, "Can't create database 'test_dqs12_full2'; database exists")
Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_dqs12_full2', or 'no' to cancel: yes
Destroying old test database 'global'...
Got an error recreating the test database: Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist
```

Any idea why this is going wrong?

Running latest homebrew +  mysql-5.6.21 + Django 1.5.5

Comment: Do you have `south` in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes, I do have `south ` in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Does changing/setting [`SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE`](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#south-tests-migrate) setting to `False` help?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the reason.

Our application has around 7 databases.  When I was about to drop them manually to get a clean state, I accidentally also dropped the `mysql` database.  This database should not be ever deleted, as it contains vital information about the root user.

When I realised this, I tried to mitigate by reinstalling MySQL via brew.

```
brew uninstall mysql
brew install mysql
```

This worked and `mysql` database showed up again when I ran `show databases;`, however the problem persisted. Thats when I came here for help.

As it seems things are a bit more complicated than that with brew. 
This is how I got it working again:

```
1) brew uninstall mysql
2) sudo rm -r /usr/local/var/mysql/
3) brew install mysql
4) unset TMPDIR
5) mysql_install_db --verbose --user='whoami' --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
6) mysql.server restart
7) mysql_secure_installation
```

Now it works. Hope this helps other fellow mac users. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Well, there are two errors indicating that the `mysql.proc` table is missing. You might be able to generate it running `mysql_update`.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. I am also unsure what you mean by running `mysql_update`. Thanks